# How to save a responseObject in a Get request AFNetworking to nsarray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I've already killed a couple terrible hours to find out how to save a `responseObject` in  a Get request `AFNetworking` to `nsarray`. Can't figure out how to save it so I could use it in another part of my code.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
 }];
```

Comment: You need to parse the incoming object. AFNetworking has a built in parsing mechanism for JSON. Then you can assign it to array.

Comment: AFNetworking has a number of pre-built [response serializers](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLResponseSerialization.h) that potentially suit your needs. Could add what you are expecting as a response?

Answer (score 1):

```
__block NSArray* responseObjectArray = nil;

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[manager GET:@"example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    responseObjectArray = (NSArray*)responseObject;
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```